# Missing Value Treatment avoiding bias in category

Tags: missing-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a customer information data .. One of the variable is Income(Numeric) with missing value. I computed the mean (treated outlier first) and then replaced the missing value with the mean value of Income variable. Now I need to categorize this income as . "high income" , "Mid INcome" , "Low Income".
As I replaced the missing value with the mean value one of the category will be biased as it will hold all the missing value observation along with others.

Is there any way to avoid this ? or what will be the appropriate method in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The result is not biased because you use mean imputation, you obtain incorrect inference: the standard errors are too small. Use multiple imputation and threshold the multiply imputed value of mean income to obtain correct CIs and p-values.

Comment: Can you please be more elaborate regarding multiple imputation, I have just started with data analysis , though I am searching for this topic .. more explanation will be really helpful ..

Comment: @SumaiyaKhatun Let me suggest you familiarize yourself with the topic by doing some self-directed research first. There are numerous resources online describing it, as well as implementations in virtually all statistical software.

Comment: @SumaiyaKhatun there are many [threads on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-imputation) dealing with multiple imputation. Also, try [this site](http://www.stefvanbuuren.nl/mi/MI.html) for a good overview.